# node.js: Is there a way for the callback function of child_process.exec() to return the process PID

Tags: node.js, exec

## Node.JS Exec Question:

I have a program which spawns multiple processes, and I'd like to log the order of the processes finishing by capturing the PID when the process finishes.  From what I can tell the standard callbacks do not include the PID (stdout,stderr,and error).

I'd like to avoid using spawn, but it looks like I'll have to, unless any kind souls have some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

To clarify:

```
var child = child_process.exec(..., function() {
    console.log( child.pid );
});
```

will not work for multiple processes.  This returns the last process, not the process which triggered the call back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var child = child_process.exec(..., function() {
    console.log( child.pid );
});
```

I highly suggest reading [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) - you might find answers to all your questions there. :)

**// EDIT** If you are using a loop to create processes, then use it like that:

```
var create_child = function( i ) {
    // creates a seperate scope for child variable
    var child = child_process.exec(..., function() {
        console.log( child.pid );
    });
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // does not create a seperate scope
    create_child( i );
}
```

to avoid scoping issues.

Comment: I should have clarified from the get go (and I have done so now in the question) that this does not work for multiple processes.  If another "child" starts, that becomes the child.pid and the previous pid becomes lost.  That's why I'm trying to use the callback to get the PID.

Comment: @DanSteingart It definetly works. If it returns last process, then you need to wrap everything in anonymous function. Show us your code and I'll show you how to use it so it works correctly. What you are talking about is actually a scoping issue.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I ended up using spawn in a similar context (and I wanted to capture the stream anyhow, see the answer below).

Comment: Now if you'd only edit out the RTFM comment the answer would get a check :-p

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for helping me understand scope.  There is one odd behavior: I had to add 1 to the resulting PID number to get this to work.  Any ideas why?  With spawn that was not the case.

Comment: @DanSteingart I'm glad it works. I have no idea why you had to add 1.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and a brief coffee break, I'm convinced that child_process.spawn is the way to go.  Making an object array to handle the processes, and deleting those process objects on exit seems to work well.

See: https://gist.github.com/3990987