# NodeJs: Detect when program started with child_process.spawn is ready?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, child-process

I use the [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) function from node's child process module to start mpv player and then communicate through a unix socket with it.

My problem is, that when spawning mpv it is not yet ready and right away. I'd like something like a callback or a promise to see when the mpv process is ready.

```
spawn('mpv', arguments, function() {
    // mpv ready
});
```

I though about using a promise by "pinging" the socket and resolve it, when it is successful. But I'm not very familiar with promises yet.

Does anybody happen to have some experience with that?

Comment: Similar questions here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162136/node-js-is-there-a-way-for-the-callback-function-of-child-process-exec-to-ret

Comment: I've found that before but it is about `exec` and not `spawn`. The callback in  exec returns when the process terminates. But in my case mpv does and should not terminate.

Comment: `My problem is, that when spawning mpv it is not yet ready and right away.` ready to do what ? besides, https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mpv

Comment: Ready to accept messages through the IPC socket, in other terms completely "booted". You have linked me to my own project by the way, I'm needing this for node-mpv :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, why you want to do this in promise way, you can do some code when you recive some data in data handler..

I think, you can try with promise in this way

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function spawnAsyncFunction() {
    var proc = spawn('ls', ['-l']);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        proc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            resolve(data);
        });
        proc.on('close', function (code) {
            reject(code);
        });

    })

}
spawnAsyncFunction()
    .then(function(data){
        // Some usful code here
        console.log(data.toString());
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: That might be a solution. Though I have to try if mpv actually sends some data when you just start it with `--idle`. Personally I don't *want* to do it in a promise way (not really a fan of promises) but I just thought it might be a possible solution. If you're in for a non promise solution I'm all for it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I start mpv with `--idle` and `--quiet` which leaves the player running forever and suppressed every console output. Thus `proc.stdout.on` should never receive any **data** and the promise would never resolve, right?

Comment: Yes,  if no data streams in to stdout this promise would never resolve

Comment: But you can send some data to stdout. Just call two command for spawn ('date & mpv ',...

Comment: Ha I thought of the same thing but "mpv & something", but because mpv doesn't terminate it didn't work :D But this will resolve as soon as date put out something, it doesn't guarantee, that mpv is 'ready', does it. Thank you very much for your time btw :)